# How to write there exists exactly 1 x in a domain with property p without the unique quantifier?

Tags: logic

I need to write the statement 'there exists exactly one x in a domain such that p(x) is true'. This needs to be done without using the uniqueness quantifier $\exists!$. I've been staring at this problem for a while and I honestly haven't a clue how to approach this.

Comment: Unique is with the exclamation. Are you looking for something like $\exists x \in ...$

Comment: There exists at least one, and there exists at most one (that is, any two of them are equal).

Comment: is there a way to rewrite the statement without using the existential quantifier with the exclamation?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

$$
\exists x \in X,\; (p(x) \wedge (\forall y \in X,\; p(y) \rightarrow y=x))
$$

That is, there is at least one element for which $p$ holds, and any element for which $p$ holds is the same.

Comment: so that means that there exists at least one y in the domain X such that y having the property p means that y and x are the same?

Comment: Yes, it's all the elements $y$ where $y=x$ (i.e. just the one, $x$ itself).

Comment: Not quite. Luke's answer says that there is a solution, $ x$, and that *every* solution is equal to $ x$.  Meaning that $ x $ is the only solution.

Comment: Let me rewrite the answer with parenthesis so you can see the two implications: $\left(\exists x \in X,\; p(x)\right) \wedge \left(\forall y \in X,\; p(y) \rightarrow y=x \right)$

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding the uniqueness quantifier which is $\exists!$ as noted in the comments, you could write for the domain $X$

$$\exists x_0 \in X: \forall x \in X: (x=x_0 \wedge p(x)) \vee (x\neq x_0 \wedge \neg p(x) )$$

This is just saying that when $x$ is your special value $x_0$, $p(x)$ is true; otherwise it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be done if the language has equality i.e., there's a binary predicate "=" which satisfies the equality axioms.

I don't want to spoil the punchline for you, but if you don't see it immediately, think about how you prove the uniqueness of the identity element in a group.

Comment: I danced around your idea for proofing it for about one hour, but still couldn't figure out of proof can you give a more straight-forward hint??

Comment: In a group, you prove the uniqueness of the identity by supposing that $e$ and $e'$ are both solutions to the identity axioms, i.e., $\forall x\, ex=x=xe$.  Then consider the term $ee'$.  Since both $e$ and $e'$ satisfy the identity axioms, we must have $e=ee'=e'$.

So what was the structure of this argument?  We created an identity predicate $I$ and proved $$\forall e \forall e' \, I(e) \& I(e') \to e=e'.$$